# Polymer: Ensure execution of one polymer element before another

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

In my index file, I use two custom polymer elements; geo-location and gis-service. The purpose of the first one is to get the current location of the user, then the latitude and longitude are fed to gis-service. 
Part of the index file:

```
<geo-location watchpos></geo-location>
<template is="auto-binding">
    <gis-service id="gservice" latitude="{{latitude}}" longitude="{{longitude}}">Use lat and long here</gis-service>
</template>
```

I update latitude and longitude for gis-service via:

```
var t = document.querySelector('template');
var geolocation = document.querySelector('geo-location');
geolocation.addEventListener('geo-response', function(e) {
          t.latitude = this.latitude.toFixed(6);
          t.longitude = this.longitude.toFixed(6);
 });
```

However, when latitude and longitude are passed to gis-service it shows they are undefined. I suspect that gis-service is called/executed before I assign latitude and longitude. So my question is, how to make sure that geo-location element is called and (to get latitude and longitude) before I assign them to gis-service element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [conditional template](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#conditional-templates) to check if some value is present.

So, it would be as:

```
 <template if="{{latitude}}">
   <template if="{{longitude}}">
    <gis-service id="gservice" latitude="{{latitude}}" longitude="{{longitude}}">Use lat and long here</gis-service>
  </template></template>
```